# Post array limit?

Tags: php, html

I have problem when post many row data in my tabular input, i only see 500 rows.

here my code for detail:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
}
?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++){?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="input" name="attributes[<?= $i ?>][value]" value="<?= $i ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="input" name="attributes[<?= $i ?>][name]" value="<?= 'name'. $i ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>

    </table>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP introduced the max_input_vars config option, which is defaulted to a value of 1000. Check out the Runtime Configuration section of the PHP manual.

The value can be changed by updating the server's php.ini, adding an .htaccess file, or adding a line to httpd.conf.

Answer (score 3):

Rutunj sheladiya tells you all about max_input_vars limit, which is your main question.

My solution was to json_encode the array so you only send a encoded string. Then in the destination server you must json_decode the array.

I think it's a clean solution since it can be a huge array and you couldn't know its size.

Now this only may be limited with the max_post_size if the json encoded string's size is higher than the value you have configured.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing  [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) as well. More information: [PHP max_input_vars and big forms.](https://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/)

Answer (score 1):

Limit can be identified using `max_input_vars` which is default `1000`.

If you have multiple arrays with unknown indexes, then you must need to change `max_input_vars` in **php.ini** file.